# Angular - Push API response into an array

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a situation where i need to push the response of an API called to an array. Previously, I hard coded the data like this.

```
filterrole = [
{ text: 'Supervisor', value: 'Supervisor' },
{ text: 'Administrator', value: 'Administrator'},
{ text: 'Maintainer', value: 'Maintainer' }
];
```

But now, i need to get the data from the backend. The backend query is fine. this is how the result looks like from the backend called.

```
["Supervisor","Maintainer","Observer","Administrator"]
```

the filterrole has it own class which consist of text and value variable.

***Role.class***

```
export class Role {
text: string;
value: string;
}
```

My question is, how do I push the response from the API call into the filterrole variable ? Below is my workaroud.

```
export class AddGroupComponent implements OnInit {
     filterrole: Role [];
     ngOnInit() {
          this.getDistinctRole();
     }

     getDistinctRole(): void {
     this._dashboardservice.getDistinctRole().subscribe(
        resp => {
           // what should i do here to push the data into
           // filterdata.text and filterdata.value
        },
        err => {
           this.loading = false;
           this._nzMessage.create('error', `Error occurred: ${err.message}`);
       }
     );
 }
```

Comment: Why do you need separate properties for the same value (according to the first code snippet)?

Comment: @Edric probably some third party control (combobox ?) requires it in this format.

Comment: @Edric hi edric. the first code snippet is the hard coded part. Now i need to get the value from the API call which read the data from the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do like this as well

```
export class AddGroupComponent implements OnInit {
     filterrole = [];
     ngOnInit() {
          this.getDistinctRole();
     }

     getDistinctRole(): void {
     this._dashboardservice.getDistinctRole().subscribe(
        resp => {
           this.fliterRole(resp);
        },
        err => {
           this.loading = false;
           this._nzMessage.create('error', `Error occurred: ${err.message}`);
       }
     );
      filterRole(result) {
         for(let i =0; i < result.length; i++) {
            this.filterrole.push({ text: result[i], value: result[i] });
       }
 }
```

this is working example 
https://codesandbox.io/s/525xw2097n

Comment: Could you please explain this code snippet in some detail? This can help others who want to know how this code snippet is different from the code snippet that OP posted or those who want to know what the code actually does.

Comment: @Edric thank you for your suggestion  i have added working code please check that

Answer (score 1):

Just do it like this

```
   resp => {
            this.filterrole = resp.map(x => ( {text: x, value: x } )) 
        },
```

and change the Role class to an interface

```
export interface Role {
  text: string;
  value: string;
}
```

Or if you still want to have it as a class then create a constructor

```
export class Role {
  constructor(public value: string, public text: string) 
}
```

and then

```
 resp => {
            this.filterrole = resp.map(x => new Role(x,x)); 
        },
```

or if you want just mutate the array without reassigning:

```
resp => {
               resp.forEach(x =>  this.filterrole.push(new Role(x,x)) ); 
        },
```

but in this case don't forget to initalize filterrole somewhere.

Comment: Thank you so much for the effort sir. I really appreciate it.. i really new to this angular and typescript. this kind of example really help me to understand more.

Answer (score 0):

You can push the api response with below code. let me know if you had any trouble assigning to it.

```
`resp => {
    // what should i do here to push the data into
    // filterdata.text and filterdata.value
    for (i in resp.data) { 
    filterrole.push(resp[i]);
    }
}`
```